# Using ng-init with async operations

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use ng-init that make an async call whilst inside an ng-repeat?

For example consider the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <md-list>
        <md-list-item>
            {{order.id}}
        </md-list-item>

        <md-list-item ng-init="detail = getOrderDetail(order.id)">
            {{detail.itemName}}
        </md-list-item>
    </md-list
</div>
```

I'd like to call a function for each item being repeated over which will go and fetch some extra data over http.

So in my getOrderDetail I have something this kind of thing:

```
function getOrderDetail(id) {
    return myService.getOrderDetails(id).then(function(orderDetail){
        return orderDetail;
    }); 
}
```

This doesnt work for me, as the `detail.itemName` in my second `md-list-item` does not resolve to anything, but I can see the network request made and if I add a breakpoint in my function call I do see the order detail returned with the `itemName` property present.

Is there a limitation when using ng-init that prevents it working\re-evaluating for async operations?

Thanks

Comment: using ng-init here doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There I can see couple of things wrong implemented

1. Another wrong thing is you shouldn't be using `ng-init` for this case
2. This is not how you can make it working, like you are considering that, data returned from promise will directly put inside a variable.

I'd make those call when I get data & will put data in `order` object of that element so that I can grab details later from that particular order only

```
angular.forEach(orders, function(order){
    getOrderDetail(id).then(function(response){
       order.detail = response;
    })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <md-list>
        <md-list-item>
            {{order.id}}
        </md-list-item>
        <md-list-item>
            {{order.detail.itemName}}
        </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoter could you please explain write in comment why downvote? please put a comment if you feel something wrong, I'd appreciate it. Also the same will help me to improve further..

Comment: @KevinB thanks for heads up sir, but  is that the reason behind downvote?

Comment: Thanks - I did end up doing something like this already, it was more a question of whether this use of ng-init was possible and suitable which you have answered.

Comment: @mindparse still wondering who downvoted & why? :( I wanted to know where I'm wrong, If I'm (just to improve myself)

Comment: @KevinB any other wrong thing with answer, you felt ?